# fill mapped array in php controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am passing an array from controller to view in PHP CodeIgniter.
Here is my code in controller.
`$gen` is any array containing many values.

```
foreach ($gen as $value) {
    $moviesbyid['similarmovie'] = $this->main_model->getsimilarmovies($value);
}

$this->load->view('home/check.php', $moviesbyid);
```

But the above code fill `$moviesbyid['similarmovie']` array only for one value of `$value`.
I want that it contain all the values returned from `getsimilarmovies($value)` for every value of $value.
How can i do this?
Here is the method in model:

```
public function getsimilarmovies($gener)
{
    $this->db->limit(4);
    $this->db->like('Genre',$gener);
    $query = $this->db->get('sources'); 
    return $query->result();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create new items in the array as it loops.
Your code just overwrite the same item every iteration.

```
foreach ($gen as $value) {
    $moviesbyid['similarmovie'][]=$this->main_model- 
    >getsimilarmovies($value);
}
```

notice the `[]`